# Passing arguments to a function via list and ignoring unused arguments

Tags: r, function, arguments, scoping, do.call

## Background

I'm interested in using `do.call` to pass arguments to two functions with use of one list. The `do.call` solution should ignore unused arguments.

### Example

```
my_sum <- function(a, b) {
    a + b
}

my_exp <- function(c, d) {
    c^d
}

args_to_use <- as.list(1:4)
names(args_to_use) <- letters[1:4]

my_wrapper <- function(fun_args = args_to_use) {
    res_one <- do.call(my_sum, fun_args)
    res_two <- do.call(my_exp, fun_args)
    res_one + res_two
}
```

*Naturally, the example fails as superfluous arguments are passed to both functions.*

## Desired results

```
my_wrapper_two <- function(fun_args = args_to_use) {
    res_one <- do.call(my_sum, fun_args[1:2]) # Only a, b
    res_two <- do.call(my_exp, fun_args[3:4]) # Only c, d
    res_one + res_two
}
my_wrapper_two()
# 84
```

### Sought solution

I would like for the subsetting operations `[1:2]` and `[3:4]` to be performed automatically depending on the function arguments.

---

## Notes

One approach I was thinking of would be using `names(formals(my_exp))` to create desired list of arguments as in:

```
my_wrapper_three <- function(fun_args = args_to_use) {
    res_one <- do.call(my_sum, fun_args[names(formals(my_sum))])
    res_two <- do.call(my_exp, fun_args[names(formals(my_exp))])
    res_one + res_two
}
my_wrapper_three()
```

This doesn't look elegant and I'm wondering if there is a more intelligent solution?

### Update

The solution I cam up with is as follows:

```
do_call_on_existing <- function(fun, args_list) {
    fun_args <- names(formals(fun))
    viable_args <- args_list[fun_args]
    viable_args <- Filter(Negate(is.null), viable_args)
    do.call(fun, viable_args)
}
```

The `Filter` / `Negate` bit prevents function from failing where `my_sum` could have extra arguments that would result in arguments list returning `null` element. So the code can work:

```
my_sum <- function(a = 999, b = 999, c = 999) {a + b + c}
my_nms <- list(a = 1, b = 2) 
do_call_on_existing(my_sum, my_nms)
```

Comment: I don’t think there’s a specific problem with your proposed solution, and I doubt you can do better (except of course packaging the whole thing into a reusable function). Note that it’s recommended to pass *string function names* as the first argument to `do.call` instead of the actual function, since that drastically improves error messages.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks, I was thinking of wrapping `do.call` and using `formals` there to call `do.call` on a subset only. @ekoam's answer is OK in the absence of a cleaner solution. I will also have a look at rlang's [`exec`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/exec.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (`...` allows you to pass any number of arguments into `my_sum` but only `a` and `b` are used as per your definition):

```
my_sum <- function(a, b, ...) {
    a + b
}

my_exp <- function(c, d, ...) {
    c^d
}

args_to_use <- as.list(1:4)
names(args_to_use) <- letters[1:4]

my_wrapper <- function(fun_args = args_to_use) {
    res_one <- do.call(my_sum, fun_args)
    res_two <- do.call(my_exp, fun_args)
    res_one + res_two
}
```

Comment: is (...) equivalent to Python's (*args)?

Comment: They are very similar but not exactly the same. @KarthikS

Comment: Interesting suggestion, I didn't think of using ellipsis in the original function constructs.